# Unable to get selected value from dropdownlist when click on submit button in asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

want to get dropdownlist selected value in Controller after click on Submit button

View part :-

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ExportFormat, new List<SelectListItem>()
{
     new SelectListItem(){Value="PDF", Text = "PDF"},
     new SelectListItem(){Value=".CSV", Text = ".CSV"},
     new SelectListItem(){Value="Excel", Text = "Excel"}
}, "Select Format", new { @class = "form-control editable" })

<input type="submit" value="Export file" class="btn btn-primary" name="Command" />
```

Controller Part:-

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Reports(ReportsModel model,string Command)
{
    if(Command=="PDF")
    {

    }
    else if(Command==".CSV")
    {

    }
    else if(Command=="Excel")
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Does `ReportsModel` contain a property `ExportFormat`? If so it will be bound with the selected option. And your submit button does not have a `value` attribute so it does not post a value - the value of `Command` will always be `null`. But why are you trying to use that to get the value of the `ExportFormat` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi If you want to get the value of the dropdownlist control, in the controller action method then you should give name of the dropdownlist control as a parameter in the action method.

example:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Reports(ReportsModel model,string ExportFormat)
{

}
```

Hope in your code , the name of the dropdownlist control is exportformat , kindly check that in view source and give it as a parameter , then you should surely get it.

Thanks

Karthik

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to ask a good question! However you can update your `@Html.DropDownListFor();` with following piece of code :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ExportFormat, new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
     new SelectListItem(){Value="PDF", Text = "PDF"},
     new SelectListItem(){Value=".CSV", Text = ".CSV"},
     new SelectListItem(){Value="Excel", Text = "Excel"}
    },"Model.ExportFormat", "Select Format", new { @class = "form-control 
       editable", onchange = "this.form.submit()" })
```

It will be better if you put controller's action where you are submitting the form on change!

Comment: There is no such overload!